# 'void' type not allowed into test class

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm coding a test class to test a method called setClipped within a class called Bird. To show you, this is the method I'm testing:

```
void setClipped() {
        this.feathersClipped = true;
    }
```

This is the method in which the feathersClipped value is changed:

```
boolean clipped(){
        return feathersClipped;
    }
```

And this is the test method:

```
@Test
    public void testSetClipped() {
        System.out.println("setClipped");
        Bird bird = new Bird("Ploy","Steve","Green");
        assertEquals(true, bird.setClipped());
    }
```

All the method does is change a value, featherClipped (featured the the "clipped" class to true. However, when I run the test class, I get an error message: 'void' type not allowed into test class . While I do acknowledge that the method being tested is a "void" class (meaning it doesn't return anything), is there a way to properly test the method just short of adding an accessor like this?

```
boolean getClipped(){
        return this.feathersClipped;
    }
```

Comment: You should call `setClipped` on its own line, then assert `getClipped` (which would be better named as `isClipped`) instead of asserting `setClipped`. It's also common practice for setters (`setClipped`) to accept an argument, specifying whether you want to set clipped to `true` or `false`: `setClipped(true)`, although if you want to avoid "un-clipping", then you can simply leave `setClipped` as it is. You cannot pass `setClipped` into the `assert` method because it does not return a value (it's `void`)

Comment: assertEquals asserts that two booleans are equal.  The problem is that you are comparing a boolean and void, meaning nothing, in the line assertEquals(true, bird.setClipped()); because the setClipped method returns void